# windows 10 local logon scripts issues

Tags: windows-10, user-profile, logon-scripts

I am trying to work out how to best use Windows 10 logon scripts on a computer that is NOT domain joined:

I know that I can apply a .bat file for 'all users' in this location:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp

and I can apply a .bat file for a 'single user' in this location:
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

and this works..

However I am trying to work out how to use the 'Logon Script' in the profile tab of the user's properties (Computer Management > Local Users and Groups > Users)?

If I enter a .bat name in 'Logon Script' does this link to another folder where I can store other .bat files (as I could do with a domain Joined PC)

Thanks for your assistance..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that works:

1. Create folders to make the path C:\Windows\sysvol\Sysvol[Computer name]\scripts\example.bat
2. Go to the properties of the "scripts" folder you just made, and under the "Share" tab, use "Advanced Sharing" to share the folder with the name "Netlogon".
3. In the "Logon script" section of the "Profile" tab of the user in Computer Management, put in example.bat, just like you would do in Windows Server ADUC.

Edit: Step 1 may be unnecessary. You can probably just create a folder and share it as "Netlogon" instead of imitating sysvol like I did.